# HTTP 415 - Unsupported media type

Tags: java, apache, http, jax-rs, shiro

I'm using jax-rs and trying to integrate with Apache Shiro, so I'm doing a basic method like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public Response get(@Auth Subject subject) {
        subject.checkPermission("protected:read");
        JSONObject rta = new JSONObject();
        rta.put("user", "mauricio");
    return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity(rta.toJSONString()).build();
}
```

After making a request I get the following error in the console:

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject, and Java type interface org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: application/octet-stream is a generic content type. Try using a specific content type and see what happens (eg, "Content-Type: text/html" in the headers or something like that).

Comment: I Already tried to add a content type. Consumes and Produces but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Could you sniff the traffic and see what "Accept: " headers the client is sending?

Comment: Whats your import for @Auth ?